# xterm ignores xrdb state unless loaded twice

Tags: x11, colors, xterm, x-server, dot-files

When I boot up i3, my xterm will be colored and configured as though my Xresources haven't been loaded yet, with default values for everything, but when I query the resource database, all my values will be properly set. This persists even when opening additional terminals, so I don't think this is a timing issue with startup. An example of querying my xrdb is here:

```
    *.borderWidth:  0
    *background:    #282828
    *color0:        #282828
    *color1:        #cc241d
    *color10:       #b8bb26
    *color11:       #fabd2f
    *color12:       #83a598
    *color13:       #d3869b
    *color14:       #8ec07c
    *color15:       #ebdbb2
    *color2:        #98721a
    *color3:        #d79921
    *color4:        #458588
    *color5:        #b16286
    *color6:        #689d6a
    *color7:        #a89984
    *color8:        #928374
    *color9:        #fb4934
    *cursorColor:   #ebdbb2
    *customization: -color
    *foreground:    #ebdbb2
    *root:  #282828
    facename:       -xos4-terminus-medium-*-*-*-16-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
    xterm*font:     -xos4-terminus-medium-*-*-*-16-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

If I use xrdb to load my ~/.Xresources file again, the results of querying are the same (albeit in a different order, but xterm will have proper settings as expected. Here's an example of the output after loading the xrdb with ~/.Xresources again.

```
$xrdb -q
*foreground:    #ebdbb2
*background:    #282828
*root:  #282828
*cursorColor:   #ebdbb2
*color0:        #282828
*color8:        #928374
*color1:        #cc241d
*color9:        #fb4934
*color2:        #98721a
*color10:       #b8bb26
*color3:        #d79921
*color11:       #fabd2f
*color4:        #458588
*color12:       #83a598
*color5:        #b16286
*color13:       #d3869b
*color6:        #689d6a
*color14:       #8ec07c
*color7:        #a89984
*color15:       #ebdbb2
xterm*font:     -xos4-terminus-medium-*-*-*-16-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
facename:       -xos4-terminus-medium-*-*-*-16-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
*.borderWidth:  0
```

I have no idea why this fixes it. My ~/.xinitrc doesn't seem to be improperly set up. This is everything in there.

```
#!/bin/sh

# /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#
# global xinitrc file, used by all X sessions started by xinit (startx)

#merge xresources
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge -I "$HOME" ~/.Xresources

#xinitrc only customization
#bg=$(xrdb -query | grep *.background); bg="${bg: -7}"
xsetroot -solid \#282828

# invoke global X session script
. /etc/X11/Xsession
```

Comment: Are you really booting a clean X11 session rather than KDE/Gnome or the multitude of other window managers?  I would put a `touch` command into `~/.xinitrc` to check if it is being called, which it won't if you are using a modern window manager. FWIW, I don't use `~/.Xresources`,  rather `~/.Xdefaults`.

Comment: @Bib Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm booting into i3. `~/.xinitrc` is definitely being executed, adding `touch` creates a file exactly the way you'd expect it to. Running `export` on a variable works as well.